# Using three.js GLTFLoader() with typescript - conflict with zimjs

Tags: javascript, typescript, three.js, nuxt.js

I'm loading a model fine with three.js GLTFLoader() using typescript in a nuxt.js app:

```
this.mGLTFLoader = new (<any>THREE).GLTFLoader();
this.mGLTFLoader.load(pPath, (gltf) => this.onLoad(gltf), (xhr) => this.onProgress(xhr), (e) => this.onError(e));
```

But when I load zimjs (a JavaScript library) I'm getting some conflict:

> TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided. at GLTFLoader.js:2000

Answer (score 1):

Solved. It was a conflict between zim's Blob to the document.Blob

Comment: Yes - ZIM stores the JavaScript Blob on the document.  But that might not help the other library.  So run ZIM with the namespace turned on (call zns=true before importing the ZIM js).  Then if you want to use ZIM without the namespace but protect the JavaScript Blob use zimplify("Blob"); You will then need the namespace for Blob but not other ZIM functions.